# Windows Store App - Test In-App Purchase

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm working on a Windows Store app. This app allows the user to pay for an upgrade in the app. The upgrade simply removes the advertisements (for now). I submitted my app for certification. However, it failed. I suspect the reason it failed is because of 1.2 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx).

More specifically, I believe its because I did not provide a way for testers to test purchases. My question is, how do I do that? The certification doesn't say anything about that. But the certification report I received said a possible reason for failure was: "Can users make purchases through the app? If so, you need to provide a way to test those purchases.".

My app does not require a username/password, so I don't have a way of identifying the user. How do I know its a tester to allow them to test purchases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they mean you should provide a step-by-step description of how to find your Upgrade button and test the additional functionality of your App?
The Microsoft test team needs to verify that your Upgrade features are working properly.

In your case you would have to write something like this in the App Store Description:

- Go to into the main menu and click the Upgrade button.
- As you can see, all advertisements are removed from the app.
- Places that have advertisements before buying the Upgrade:

  - Welcome screen
  - ...
  - ....